# is there a vimscript equivalent for Ruby's strip() (strip leading and trailing spaces)?

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a VimScript function that strips any trailing or leading spaces before a string.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since [8.0.1630](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/295ac5ab5e840af6051bed5ec9d9acc3c73445de) vim has `trim()`.

For older version: assuming you're trying to do this on a variable in vimscript, you can do this:

```
let new_var = substitute(var, '^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$', '\1', '')
```

You could always make you're own function if you like:

```
function! Strip(input_string)
    return substitute(a:input_string, '^\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$', '\1', '')
endfunction

let new_var = Strip(var)
```

Comment: I used to write this as `substitute(str, '^\s\+\|\s\+$', '', 'g')`. It is surprising, but your variant works a bit faster.

Comment: @Zyx: I think my variant is faster because it's always anchored to the start of the line, so the parser doesn't have to try to match from every single character (this also means it doesn't need the 'g' flag to make it keep trying).

Comment: `\v` ftw:  `substitute(var,'\v^\s*(.{-})\s*$','\1','')`

Comment: You might want to use `\_s` instead of `\s` to handle new lines as well. That is the default behaviour of `trim()`

Comment: how should i read the ^\s... expression, i am attempting to strip a leading character

Comment: With my function, just in case `trim()` turned out to be much faster than the substitution, I also added `if has('nvim') || v:versionlong >= 8001630` to use trim(), otherwise I use the substitution.

Answer (score 21):

Since [8.0.1630](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/295ac5ab5e840af6051bed5ec9d9acc3c73445de) vim has a built-in `trim()` function to do this. From the docs:

> `trim({text}[, {mask}])`
>
> ```
>   Return {text} as a String where any character in {mask} is
>   removed from the beginning and  end of {text}.
>   If {mask} is not given, {mask} is all characters up to 0x20,
>   which includes Tab, space, NL and CR, plus the non-breaking
>   space character 0xa0.
>   This code deals with multibyte characters properly.
> ```

From version [8.2.0868](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/2245ae18e3480057f98fc0e5d9f18091f32a5de0), a third optional argument allows to specify whether to trim from begin, end, or both:

> `trim({text} [, {mask} [, {dir}]])`
>
> ```
>  The optional {dir} argument specifies where to remove the
>  characters:
>      0   remove from the beginning and end of {text}
>      1   remove only at the beginning of {text}
>      2   remove only at the end of {text}
>  When omitted both ends are trimmed.
> ```

So, calling `trim(var)` will strip leading and trailing whitespace from `var`.

Comment: Trim now takes a third argument to determine if it should trim from start, end, or both!